# algorithm to compute the integral orthogonal group

Tags: nt.number-theory, gr.group-theory

Suppose I have an indefinite quadratic form over the integers, and I want to compute its orthogonal group. Is there an algorithm, or at least a heuristic? If yes, is there any implementation anywhere?

Comment: Please define "compute". Do you mean a finite set of generators?

Comment: @Marguax For my current purpose a finite set of generators will do. As I am sure you know, in general knowing a finite set of generators tells you very little about the group (for example, it is probably undecidable to find the presentation), so I am guessing this is hard here also.

Comment: This is very close to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/136338
("Does anyone know of any papers in which structural aspects of 
 the orthogonal group of some indefinite non-unimodular integral lattice 
 are calculated?").  See also http://mathoverflow.net/questions/141284
(asking for generators of the automorphisms of the diagonal form $(19,5,-1)$).

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies, right, the new user "few_reps" indicated that there would be a preprint on the arxiv but was not otherwise specific. I'm guessing that the author of the preprint will not be named "few_reps"

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies Yes, I remembered Will's question (I couldn't remember the title, otherwise I would have referred to it), but I remembered that there was no clear answer, and on revisiting your link, there still is not, though it may be that Vinberg's paper is the answer. By the way, I could not find any allusion by few_reps to a paper of his on arxiv.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies in fact, it seems that Vinberg's algorithm is at least formulated only for forms looking like $-k x_0^2 + \sum_{i=1}^n x_i.$ I don't know how crucial that is...

Comment: Igor, now that I think of it, one standard item, as in the Leech lattice, is $Q(x_1,\ldots, x_n) + 2 y z,$ where $Q$ was positive. See SPLAG.

Comment: @WillJagy Where $y, z$ are two of the $x$ or some linear forms, or new variables (the last case is sort of similar to the case I had mentioned...)

Comment: Hi, Igor. They are new variables.  In the first edition of SPLAG, chapter 26, Lorentzian Forms for the Leech Lattice, and chapter 27, The Automorphism Group of the 26-Dimensional Lorentzian Lattice. Pretty much the entire book, really. Then at least the second edition of Lattices and Codes by Wolfgang Ebeling, especially section 4.5, Automorphism Groups.

Comment: Igor, from the edit history, few_reps had a mention of an arxiv piece in versions 1,2,3 but not in version 4, which is how it stands now. It almost seems that that question became the test case for a new method...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the group you are looking for is arithmetic, you could in principle apply the algorithms from *Some general algorithms. I: Arithmetic groups* by Fritz J. Grunewald and Daniel Segal. However, to my knowledge nobody has implemented these algorithms and they would probably be rather inefficient.

In special cases you may have a better chance.

Consider the case of a ternary quadratic form $q$ and suppose you have an order $\mathcal{O}$ in an indefinite quaternion algebra over $\mathbb{Q}$ such that $q$ is the restriction of the reduced norm on the trace zero submodule of $\mathcal{O}$ (for example, this will be the case for the quadratic form $q(x,y,z)=abx^2-ay^2-bz^2$ by choosing the order $\mathbb{Z}+\mathbb{Z}i+\mathbb{Z}j+\mathbb{Z}ij$ where $i^2=a, j^2=b$ with nonzero $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}$, not both negative). Then the orthogonal group of $q$ is isomorphic to $\Gamma=N(\mathcal{O})/\mathbb{Q}^*$ where $N(\mathcal{O})$ is the normalizer of $\mathcal{O}$ in $B^*$. The finite index subgroup $\Gamma^+$ of elements of positive norm in $\Gamma$ is a Fuchsian group with finite covolume, so a presentation for this group can be found efficiently, for example by applying the algorithms from *Computing fundamental domains for Fuchsian groups* by John Voight that are available in [Magma](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/). From there you can go back to the group you are interested in.

More generally if your quadratic form has signature $(n,1)$ you should be able to compute a fundamental domain for the orthogonal group acting on the hyperbolic $n$-space, but I do not know any implementation that would do it directly. If $n=3$ you can use my algorithms from *Computing arithmetic Kleinian groups* that are [implemented in Magma](http://www.normalesup.org/~page/software.html), but first you have to relate your quadratic form to some quaternion algebra (see *The arithmetic of hyperbolic 3-manifolds* by Colin Maclachlan and Alan W. Reid, section 10 for details).

Edit : let's do the construction for your example $A = \begin{pmatrix}0&1&1&1\\1&0&1&1\\1&1&0&1\\1&1&1&0\end{pmatrix}$.

Since this quadratic form is isotropic with discriminant $-3$, we know that the orthogonal group is commensurable with the Bianchi group of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$.

Let $L$ be the $\mathbb{Z}$-module generated by $\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$, $\begin{pmatrix}0&-1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$, $\begin{pmatrix}1&-1\\1&-1\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}-j&-1\\1&-j-1\end{pmatrix}$ where $j$ denotes a third root of unity. Then you can check that the Gram matrix of the determinant in this base is $A$ (in general, such an $L$ is given by a Clifford algebra construction).

Let $\sigma$ be the nontrivial automorphism of $F=\mathbb{Q}(j)$, $R=\mathbb{Z}[j]$, $\mathfrak{p}$ the unique prime above $3$. Define an action of $\mathrm{GL}_2(F)$ on $\mathrm{M}_2(F)$ by $g\cdot m = gmg^{-\sigma}$. Let $G = \{g\in\mathrm{GL}_2(F)\ |\ \det(g)\in\mathbb{Q}\text{ and }g\cdot L = L\}$. Then general arguments show that $\Gamma = G/\mathbb{Q}^*\simeq SO^+(A;\mathbb{Z})$ with the action we defined.

Let $I = L+jL$. Then every element stabilizing $L$ also stabilizes $I$. It is easy to see that $I = \{m\in\mathrm{M}_2(R)\ |\ \mathrm{tr}(m)\in\mathfrak{p}\}$. The (projective) stabilizer of $I$ is $\mathrm{PGL}_2(R)$ (the stabilizer contains this group, and this group is maximal). Let $V=\sqrt{-3}\mathrm{id}\mathbb{Q}+\mathrm{ker}(\mathrm{tr})\cap\mathrm{M}_2(\mathbb{Q})$. Then $L=V\cap I$, and every matrix with determinant in $\mathbb{Q}^*$ stabilizes $V$. Since every matrix in $\mathrm{GL}_2(R)$ is proportional to a matrix with rational determinant, we have $\Gamma = \mathrm{PGL}_2(R)$. The generators computed by my code are $\begin{pmatrix}-j&j\\0&-j-1\end{pmatrix}$, $\begin{pmatrix}-j&j+1\\0&j+1\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}-1&0\\-j-1&1\end{pmatrix}$, and the corresponding orthogonal matrices are

$g_1 = \begin{pmatrix}-1&0&-1&0\\-1&-1&0&0\\1&0&0&0\\-1&0&0&-1\end{pmatrix}$,

$g_2 = \begin{pmatrix}0&0&0&1\\0&1&0&0\\1&0&0&0\\0&0&1&0\end{pmatrix}$,

and

$g_3 = \begin{pmatrix}-1&0&-1&0\\0&0&-1&-1\\0&0&1&0\\0&-1&-1&0\end{pmatrix}$,
but you can use your favorite generators for $\mathrm{PGL}_2(R)$ instead.

Comment: Truly you are wise in the ways of science :)

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, but thank you :)

Comment: I mean exactly what I say (by the way, in the comment to few_reps' answer I give the quadratic form, so maybe you can see if this is something you already know...) Thanks!

Comment: I have added your example. Hopefully I didn't make any mistake. Of course the computation is less straightforward than with few_reps's method.

Comment: It should be correct now :)

Answer (score 3):

I am currently writing such an algorithm (in Magma) for Lorentzian lattices. It is almost finished and has already been used to answer [this question on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/141284/integral-orthogonal-group-for-indefinite-ternary-quadratic-form/141300#141300).

It furnishes a fundamental domain for the action of the group of automorphisms $G$ of the lattice on the hyperbolic space, and identifies the boudary components. Thus it may be used to obtain a finite presentation of $G$.

Perhaps this algorithm will be available directly on Magma someday ... Now if you have an example in head, just tell me, I can perform the computations for you (if your example in not too twisted ... computations become quickly heavy).

Edit :

For your example : the Gram matrix is

```
A=  [0 1 1 1]
    [1 0 1 1]
    [1 1 0 1]
    [1 1 1 0]
```

A fundamental domain is the convex hull of the following 4 points :

```
a=(0,0,1,1), b=(0,1,1,1), d=(1,1,1,1), c=(0,0,0,1)
```

(suitably rescaling a,b,c to make them fall in $\mathcal H_3$. The point c is a cusp.)

The reflections supported by the faces of this tetrahedron are

```
[-1  1  1  1] (a,b,c)
[ 0  1  0  0]
[ 0  0  1  0]
[ 0  0  0  1]

[0 1 0 0] (a,c,d)
[1 0 0 0]
[0 0 1 0]
[0 0 0 1]

[1 0 0 0] (b,c,d)
[0 0 1 0]
[0 1 0 0]
[0 0 0 1]

[1 0 0 0] (a,b,d)
[0 1 0 0]
[0 0 0 1]
[0 0 1 0]
```

The matrices I gave in the comments below are conjugated to these.

Comment: Sure, the quad. form is: {{0, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 0}} (in mathematica format).

Comment: @few_reps: I would be happy to see your paper on arXiv soon. Reading it will be a very interesting continuation of what we discussed before. I'm interested if your method can generate Coxeter or rational-of-pi angled polytopes in dimension four.

Comment: This is a reflection group generated by 4 elements :

Comment: $[[ 1,  0,  0,  0],[ 5,  3, -1, -1],[10,  4, -1, -2],[10,  4, -2, -1]]$,

$[[0, 1, 0, 0],[1, 0, 0, 0],[0, 0, 1, 0],[0, 0, 0, 1]]$,

$[[ 2,  2,  0, -1],[ 0,  1,  0,  0],[ 2,  4,  1, -2],
[ 3,  6,  0, -2]]$,

$[[1, 0, 0, 0],[0, 1, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0, 1],[0, 0, 1, 0]]$,

(matrices act on the right)

Comment: @Sasha : I'm working on it, but have first to finish the implementation ...

Comment: @few_reps: I assume you mean that for the "usual" action one should transpose the matrices?

Comment: @IgorRivin : It looks like that ... it means that if we denote by $A$ your Gram Matrix and by M one of the matrices I wrote, then one has the equality $MAM^t=A$.

Comment: @few_reps I am a little confused. The -1 eigenvectors of two of these matrices are isotropic, so what exactly does this group look like?

Comment: @IgorRivin : Well, since matrices act on the right, you have to look at vectors $v$ such that $v.M=-v$. For example, for the first matrix, the -1 eigenvectors will be colinear to $v=( 0 , 0 , 1 ,-1)$ and one has $q(v)=-2$.

Comment: Sorry, I miscalculated. All is well.

Comment: Or not: the four faces should define a tetrahedron, but it looks like the thing they bound has one vertex inside $H^3,$ two ideal vertices and one hyperideal vertex, so the quotient is not finite volume...

Comment: @Igor : I've edited my answer to include your example.

Comment: @few_reps just to make sure I understand: your convex hull vertices are in the "original lattice", and not normalized to lie in the "standard" $H^3,$ right?

Comment: That's right ... you just have to divide each of $a$, $b$, and $d$ by the square root of the value $q$ takes on them respectively.

Comment: @few_reps: and the reflection matrices act on the right or on the left?

Comment: @few_reps: I assumed on the right, and there still something wrong with your thing (one of the angles between the faces is ArcCos[1/(4 Sqrt[3])], which is not a submultiple of pi, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Igor : Call the above matrices A,B,C,D. Then one has (AB)^6=Id,(AC)^2=Id,(AD)^2=Id,(BC)^3=Id,(BD)^2=Id,(CD)^3=Id ... Thus this reflection group seems to be the one called $\bar{V}_3$ on [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coxeter-Dynkin_diagram#Hyperbolic_Coxeter_groups) . So I don't think there is something wrong with my thing !

Comment: @few_reps strange. So, you are saying that the angles are: $\pi/6, \pi/2, \pi/2, \pi/3, \pi/2, \pi/3$ My computations are in agreement, except for that one pesky angle....

Comment: And the orientation-preserving part of that group seems to be $PGL(2, O_3)...$

Comment: @IgorRivin The link with $PGL_2(O_3)$ is almost clear : the two first basis elements furnish an hyperbolic factor. It's orthogonal is even and negative definite of determinant 3 and thus isometric to -Norm on $O_3$. This gives an isometry between your form and det on the module of $2\times 2$ herm. matrices over $O_3$...

Comment: @IgorRivin ... (continued)  The fact that the resulting morphism $PGL_(O_3)\to SO'(A)$ is an isomorphism needs a little more work (and in fact, all I can imagine for the moment is to compute the fundamental domain for both of these groups and observe that they are the same (if true)... there's probably a more arithmetic-oriented solution).